# journalctl chops lines longer then screen

Tags: log, systemd-journald

How to disable the chopping of long lines when invoking

```
journalctl -b
```

in order to see the whole journal message ?

E.g. the line get truncated:

```
Jul 09 20:47:57 myubuntu org.kde.kglobalaccel[1452]: Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adw>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be simply done by setting the **SYSTEMD_LESS** environment variable.

For instance setting **SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK** (that means S should not be in the set ) will show the message in a wrapped format.

This can be set in your .bashrc (`export SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK`) or directly in front of the journalctl command:

```
SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK journalctl -b
```

The output should now be wrapped:

```
Jul 09 20:47:57 myubuntu org.kde.kglobalaccel[1452]: Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  
"/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/8x8/legacy/"
```

More about setting the SYSTEMD_LESS variable can be found in **less(1)** and **journalctl(1)**.

From less(1) :

> **-S or --chop-long-lines**
>
> Causes  lines longer than the screen width to be chopped (truncated) rather than wrapped.  That is, the
> portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default is to wrap long
> lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.

As an alternative add the `--no-pager` flag to your journalctl command:

```
journalctl -b0 --no-pager
```